# Prevent Glympse from stopping sending my location due to low battery

Tags: applications

How can I configure [Glympse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glympse.android.glympse) so that it doesn't stop sending my location due to low battery?

[image: Screenshot_1_Glympse]

<sup>Screenshot - (Click to enlarge image)</sup>

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.